# How do you add a date created to Google Forms / Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

We have a Google Spreadsheet

It has a few columns

- Issue
- Raised By
- Date Raised

We've turned this into a Google Forms which we want anyone in the business to be able to answer.

The problem is that there doesn't seem to be a way to add the current date/time-stamp in the date raised column for each new row that is added.

Is this something that form/spreadsheet is able to do? If so how?

Answer (score 1):

When you visit the Form responses in the actual spreadsheet, is there not a timestamp that is automatically added? You shouldn't need a separate form question to collect this. The first column should be labeled "Timestamp"